# Pass search strategy to filter from rest URI

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

First time using api-platform and Symfony 4 to create an API interface for a MySQL db.

I'm updating an old search interface for the db for which I need to replicate many of the search options. This includes being able to search on a given field using various matching operators/strategies. e.g. starts with, contains exactly equals, etc.

I've set everything up for the api using Annotations.

The @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"fieldname": "strategy"} annotation on my table class works as designed, but I am limited to one-and-only-one strategy per field. I need to be able to pass the strategy to the api search function in the url. something like:

`/api/staff?lastname[start]=dav`

or

`/api/staff?lastname=david&match=contains`

or

`/api/staff/lastname/son?searchtype=end`

would be fine.

I can't figure out how to set this up. Shockingly, to me anyway, this common requirement doesn't seem to be documented at all.

Answer (score 1):

The file CustomSearchFilter.php located at the repo https://github.com/jordonedavidson/custom_search_filter solves this use-case using the

`/api/staff?lastname[start]=dav`

syntax.

The file was written by Kévin Dunglas (the author of Api Platform) and is presented with his blessing.

Comment: Thanks you and Kévin Dunglas